# Warning, FIREBASE_CONFIG and GCLOUD_PROJECT environment variables are missing when set environment configuration in firebase

Tags: node.js, firebase, environment-variables, api-key

I tried to store my api keys as environment variables by setting environment configuration in firebase.
this is the reference https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/config-env.
I redeployed the functions in Node 8 and could see the output JSON api key when I ran `firebase functions:config:get`.

```
"myservice":{
  "key": "******",
  "id": "******"
}
```

However, when I ran my application(TypeScript) and tried to test if I can get my apikey:

```
import * as admin from "firebase-admin";
import * as functions from "firebase-functions";
import "firebase-functions"; 
admin.initializeApp();
const key = functions.config().myservice.key;
console.log(key);
```

I got

```
Warning, FIREBASE_CONFIG and GCLOUD_PROJECT environment variables are missing. Initializing firebase-admin will fail   
TypeError: Cannot read property 'key' of undefined
```

and can not see the key in the console

Does anyone have the same issue?
Could anyone give some hints to solve this problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you're running the Firebase emulator you'll need to have the environment variables stored locally as described [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/local-emulator#set_up_functions_configuration_optional).

```
firebase functions:config:get > .runtimeconfig.json
# If using Windows PowerShell, replace the above with:
# firebase functions:config:get | ac .runtimeconfig.json
firebase functions:shell
```

Once you set your environment variables from the cli using `firebase functions:config:set`, you may also have to publish them given the output from the cli command:

```
Please deploy your functions for the change to take effect by running firebase deploy --only functions
```

And if you're running this as a unit test you can use the firebase-functions-test library to set environment variables:

```
const testEnv = functions(
  {
    projectId: "your-project-id",
  },
  "./<PATH-TO-SERVICE-ACCOUNT-KEY"
);

// Provide environment variables
testEnv.mockConfig({ someapi: { key: "abc123" } });
```